# entity framework- iterate into multiple tables using a table

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am trying to access tables in entity framework using another table, but i am getting tables as null.
e.g.
I am having 3 tables A,B and C. And A is having FK(Foreign key) of B and B is having FK of C. I am having object of A. Now I want to access C using B.
means A.B.C.

But i am getting B as null. So please give me the solution for this.

```
var a= databaseContext.A.Find(Id);
var c=a.B.C.where(x=>x.Id==SomeId);
```

Thanks in advance.

### Update:

Tables

**Commitment**  

CommitmentId(PK) 
FinancialYearAccountID(FK)

**FinancialYearAccount**
FinancialYearAccountId (PK)
AccountId(FK)

**Account**
AccountId(PK)

Now i want to access Account table from Commitment table

```
var commitment = databaseContext.Commitments.Find(1);
var account = commitment.FinancialYearAccount.Account.
               where(x => x.AccountId==SomeId)
```

I am getting Commitment Record, but FinancialYearAccount is coming as null, so it is crashing here.

Comment: Show your entities code

Comment: Show your code, please. Because, depend from scenario(you use lazyloading or not) we can asnwer this question